# DotNetZip - Extracting files that contain non-ascii characters

Tags: .net, encoding, extract, dotnetzip, mojibake

I'm trying to extract a zip archive that contains files which contain Japanese characters.

When I view the contents of them after extracting, the Japanese characters appear as gibberish.
This also happens with Winrar/Winzip which is why I was intended on creating this program.

At first I also had this problem with the filenames, but I fixed that with the encoding in the below code.

```
Dim subFolder As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInput(i))
Using zip = New ZipFile(fileInput(i), Encoding.GetEncoding(932))
    For Each f In zip
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirOutput & "\" & subFolder)
        f.Extract(dirOutput & "\" & subFolder, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
    Next
End Using
```

I have tried various methods of attempting to get file contents to encode correctly all of which have failed. When I create a text file containing Japanese characters and save it as UTF8 and add it to a new zip archive then extract it with the below code, the contents output correctly.

But I have several zip files that I've downloaded which do not behave the same way and instead have gibberish contents. I have a friend who does not have this same problem so I'm 100% sure it's not an encoding issue with the files and she uses Japanese system locale whereas I use English, but I would like to be able to extract these files without having to switch system locale.

Comment: Try installing japanese fonts. Hash the extracted files and check they have identical content.

Comment: I have Japanese fonts installed. For some reason archive files that I created myself do not have the same problem. 

The file in question which contains the gibberish characters is a settings file which contains the names of other files in the same directory. Those other files are correctly named in Japanese thanks to GetEncoding(932), but the settings file gives them gibberish names, so the application which uses this file to find those Japanese named files is unable to find them. I'm not sure what you mean by hashing the extracted files?